# Casting functions

Tags: c, function, casting

I have the following functions:

```
typedef int (*Bar)(void *, int a);
int foo (Struct *s, int b);
void *call(Bar c);
```

What does it mean when I call the function:

```
call( (Bar) foo);
```

Comment: Type "Bar" is "function that takes void*, int and returns int. Function foo takes a structure pointer and an int, returning an int. Those are close enough that casting foo into a Bar and calling it will probably do what you expect on most compilers, but no guarantees--casting function pointers is always implementation-dependent.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Converting a function pointer to another function pointer type is well defined. Calling the converted function, unless the expression has a type compatible with the function *definition* has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Are `int (*)(Struct *s, int b)` and `int (*)(void *, int a)` compatible?

Comment: @haccks: Only if `Struct` is a typedef for `void`. (I really hope it isn't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef int (*Bar)(void *, int a);
```

This defines `Bar` an alias for a pointer-to-function type, specifically for a function that takes two arguments of type `void*` and `int` and returns a result of type `int`.

```
int foo (Struct *s, int b);
```

This declares (but does not define) a function named `foo` that takes two arguments as specified.

I presume `Struct` is a typedef, but it's a poor name, easily confused with the `struct` keyword.

```
void *call(Bar c);
```

This declares a function `call` that takes an argument of type `Bar` and returns a `void*` result.

```
call( (Bar) foo);
```

`foo` is the name of the function declared earlier.  In this context, it's treated as an expression of pointer-to-function type.  This pointer value is converted to type `Bar`. Since `Bar is a pointer-to-function type, the conversion is well defined.

That converted pointer is then passed to a function named `call`. (`call` returns a `void*` result, but it's quietly ignored here; is that what you intended?)

We don't know what the `call` function does with its argument, so we can't tell what the behavior of this statement might be.

A conversion from one function pointer type to another, using a cast, is well defined, and converting *back* to the original type will yield the original value. Calling a function using a function pointer with the wrong type has undefined behavior. (You might be able to get away with it in some cases, but don't.)

Your `call` function could try to make a call via its parameter, but that call would have undefined behavior unless that parameter is converted back to the correct type.

There isn't enough information in your question to know what's going on, and the confusing names you've chosen don't help.

Comment: Yes, it's an example, actually "call" return another struct. Sorry for confusing names, I hope I will learn to name functions clearly. Thank you for answer.